# How to add a text label above a line on GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, arcore, glsurfaceview

I'm building an Android application to measure the distance between two points  with camera using "GLSurfaceView".
I have already added two points in the surface with a line in between and
all I need to do now is to add a text label above each line.

[image]

Comment: Hello , did you found any way to do this ? How did you managed to draw text on line ?
-@Ahmed Hadj Ammar

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the simplest way to do this is to put `GLSurfaceView` inside `FrameLayout` and add `TextView` at left top corner over `GLSurfaceView` for each line and set margins/translations according to the corresponding line coordinates (strat, middle or end point).